# Unknown file extension.jpg

Tags: delphi, jpeg, delphi-xe

The jpeg is in the uses section.

```
Procedure TFrmChemistry.AddBasicGroups;
var i,side: integer;
begin
Side := 0;
for i := 1 to 3 do
begin
Images[i].Diagram := TImage.Create(gbxParts);
Images[i].Diagram.Parent := TTabBasicGroups;
Images[i].Diagram.Visible :=true;
Images[i].Diagram.Picture.LoadFromFile(Images[i].Chemical); // unknown file extension.jpg
Images[i].Diagram.AutoSize := true;
Images[i].Diagram.Tag := i;
Images[i].Diagram.Top := ((Chempage.Height)Div 2) - ((Images[i].Diagram.Height) Div 2);
Images[i].Diagram.Left := 10 + side;
Images[i].Diagram.OnClick := ImageCreate;
Side := Side + Images[i].Diagram.Width;

end;
end;
```

`Images` is an array of records, `Diagram` is a `TImage`, `Chemical` is a string of the file name.
It was working originally when I was defining the string in code, but after I started defining it from a database it stopped working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe what you report to be true. Please double check the file name that you are passing.

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact that it works fine when you hard-coded the filename, but does not work when retrieving the filename from a database, I have to assume that the value from the database is malformed, such as if it has extra space/null characters at the end.  Without actually seeing the filename in question, or the full error message,  this is only an educated guess.

Comment: Thanks I'd been a huge mug and put quotation marks round the fields